# Having links to an included file by LaTeX PdfPages

Tags: pdf, latex

**How can you maintain the links in your pdf fileA which contains links to itself in the fileB which includes FileA?**

FileA has internal links to itself. I include it to FileB by Pdfpages such that

**This is in FileB**

```
\usepackage[enable-survey]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\includepdf[linktodoc=true, link=true]{fileA.pdf}
```

I have tested the following options unsuccessfully

```
linktodoc=true
link=true
thread=true
```

I am reading [this tutorial](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the following response from the creator of Pdfpages, A. Matthias.

> This is a feature that cannot be
>   implemented on the macro level. It
>   would have to be implemented in the
>   pdftex, xetex, etc. code itself.
>
> On CTAN you find a Java program called
>   `pax' that can extract and reinsert
>   some kind of links (but not all).

So there is work to be done in PDFpages.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you linked to, with the `link` option, you have to link to the inserted pages by their given link names - `<filename>.<page number>`. If you have a look at [this demonstration](http://www-hep2.fzu.cz/tex/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdf-hyp.pdf), you can see some explicit examples of doing this, as well as using `linktodoc` functionality.